# Scala share resources folder to open a file

Tags: scala

This is my folder structure and I am trying to load the "grammar.txt" file from resources folder but I get *not found* error.

```
val source = Source.fromResource("grammar.txt")
```

Folder structure:

```
➜  cfg-tools tree -L 4
.
├── build.sbt
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   └── scala
│   │       ├── Builer.scala
│   │       ├── Driver.scala
│   │       ├── tokens.scala
│   │       └── Tools.scala
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── grammar.txt
```

build.sbt

```
name := "cfg-tools"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "3.0.2"

Compile / unmanagedResourceDirectories += sourceDirectory.value / "resources"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the custom SBT configuration: just use the standard place for resources which is **`src/main/resources`** *(note that it's in `main` subfolder compared to your current structure)*.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!